# Stripe Card Element default postcode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm integrating Stripe Elements in my React project, using this simple component:

```
render () {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={event => this.onSubmit(event)}>
      <label>
        <CardElement className='Input' />
      </label>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Problem is that I already have another form above where the user enters its billing info (address, zip code, country...). is it possible to pre-fill this field with the Zip code already entered before?

I've looked into [Elements source code](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/blob/master/src/components/Element.js) and see no value option possible. Is it possible somehow to use ref option to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#elements-create (in options), you can pass the option `value`, I see here: https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/blob/master/src/components/Element.js#L26 that any viable option is allowed:

```
render () {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={event => this.onSubmit(event)}>
      <label>
        <CardElement
          className='Input'
          value={ { postalCode: this.state.postcode } }
        />
      </label>
    </form>
  )
}
```